# which web development tools and languages should i use?

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails

I started programming in january of this year and have covered a lot of ground. I have learnt javascript, ruby on rails, html, css, jquery and every now and then i like to try out some clojure but i will really get into that in the middle of next yr. I really didnt like rails and prefer using netbeans with pure javaScript, html and css, i just feel like i have more control. I really like javascript, but when it comes to sever side programming i have a problem.......for my level of experience i just feel like server side js will not be a good fit yet as it is still not as mature/user friendly as php or ruby on rails.

What server side language should i invest in, should i learn php? There is so much info on source code on php. I know that there is node.js and emerging frameworks like geddy.js but i need something more user friendly....or am i just being a woos.I would really like some help on this.

Thanks in advance

PS. Update: Thanks all for advice, i have settled on python and web2py framework. I decided between django and web2py by doing a couple of simple tutorials and preferred web2py by a huge margin.

Comment: Mmh.. from january of this year, you say? and in 11 months you learnt javascript, jquery, css, html and rails? My 2 cents: take some time to get deeper with a language and really learn how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you don't like rails, but you might want to try the newly released "Rails for Zombies" tutorials by Envy Labs: http://railsforzombies.org/. Or if you like books instead of online stuff, check out [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails)

As ben states, sinatra is nice for smallish stuff.

A few things to choose from, broken down by language and order of their complexity/learning curve:

**Ruby**

- [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)
- [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)

**Python**

- [web.py](http://webpy.org/)
- [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/)

**PHP**

- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakedc.com/)
- [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

EDIT: I removed my comment about php and added in some PHP specifics. Personally I started with Symfony but it is rather complex. Code Igniter would be a good starting place if you want to learn a PHP framework.

Comment: I also want to add that the "+1" was also for all the other useful info in this post. I didn't intend to start a which-language-is-best war, just meant to poke fun at a language that I personally dislike because it caused me a lot of headaches, and ruby was my aspirin.

Comment: I'm a Rails guy, but "stay away from PHP" is not good advice. There are millions (billions?) of lines of PHP code deployed in the wild, and if you plan on a career in web development you will likely come across it at some point. Best you know how to read and write basic PHP as part of your toolkit -- it will also help you better appreciate Ruby.

Comment: Ah, PHP guys. I used to be like that. :)

Comment: I agree with @zeletic that as a web developer it's definitely important to learn PHP, just so you can understand it and modify it when you need to. But I would not recommend doing your own development with it unless you are required to (and I say this as someone with several years of background in PHP followed by several years of background in Ruby).

Comment: I agree with Ben. My comment wasn't about putting down PHP, but rather that since I've learned more, I wouldn't start something new in it today. Yes, I agree that it is important to have experience with it though.

Comment: @Ben Lee: Probably true, but such abstract statements (that give no real informational value), are not necessary - and actually not fair towards a reader. It is hard sometimes to stay from personal dislikes, but this is not place for stuff like that, PHP is not perfect (like most of the things), and I would appreciate detailed explanation like: "stay away from PHP, because in your case: 1. ect.; 2. ect.; 3. and so on... (I removed my down vote, because of authors edit)

Comment: Why is PHP so widely used if it is so bad?

Comment: @RubyGladiator: PHP is not bad. It's just not as good as other, more modern web-focused paradigms. PHP is *easy* -- and easy is a Very Good Thing (VGT) in my book. It was the first web development platform that made web programming accessible to a very wide audience. It is widely used because when it was invented it was a revolutionary breakthrough. Prior to PHP, the dynamic part of the web was mostly handled by a complicated Perl/CGI paradigm -- not that there is anything wrong with Perl (which I like way more than PHP in fact), but the paradigm was much more difficult to use. [continued...]

Comment: So, PHP is everywhere because it was the first language that made web programming easy and fun, and it dominated the field for many years. But over time, as new more structured languages and frameworks became available, PHP started to become obsolete. The PHP language itself is full of inconsistencies and non-obvious quirks that can really cause debugging headaches (and it's not all PHPs fault really -- it's been around so long that it has to be crufty to be as backwards-compatible as possible).

Comment: So in the end -- it's not that PHP is *bad* per se. It's just that there are new web development paradigms today that are *better*. And by *better* what I really mean is -- easier to make the application you want to. You'll be able to do it in PHP. But you'll be able to do it faster in Ruby or Python.

Comment: @Ben Lee: Thanks, that is a good explanation of PHP's place in the web world. I have followed one of the links to web.py and really like what i see in python and the extensive libraries, also the google appengine support. I went to pull out a book from my shelf called Collective Intelligence, which is written in python and looks very good. The only thing is, if i choose python as my server side language i wonder if all the time i spent learning Ruby was a waste or will it actually help me learn python quicker. There seem to be a lot more support for raw python than ruby without rails.

Comment: @RubyGladiator, I only have a little bit of experience with Python, and a lot with Ruby, so I can't give a completely impartial comparison. But from the little Python I've done, I have to say it's very similar to Ruby in terms of how easy it is to accomplish various programming tasks. It is not quite as die-hard object oriented as ruby (which can be a plus or a minus), but otherwise it is pretty similar in power. Your ruby experience will definitely help you with python.

Comment: But I'm not so sure I agree with you that raw Python support is strong than raw Ruby support. Again, with my biased viewpoint, I actually think the opposite is true. There are so many ruby gems out there to accomplish any task imaginable. Python has that too, but I've personally found the support and community for Ruby better. In any case, don't equate Rails with Ruby. I think Rails is so-so okay, but Ruby is *awesome*.

Comment: I work with Python at work and with Ruby on the side for fun and I have to say that they are definitely more alike than they are different. The one thing that'll probably take time to get used to is just their slightly different syntax for things. (Significant whitespace, hanging indents, `self` in method calls, double underscores, etc.) But, if you've used ruby then I think the transition to python will be much easier than something like PHP which is very different.

Comment: Its debatable, but one thing i have noticed from some quick research is how broad python's application is vs ruby across industries. The finance and science libraries seem really cool, you even have high frequency trading firms looking for python programmers. I have worked mostly as a trader from an economics viewpoint, so its exciting to see that python has these libraries which Ruby doesn't because i looked but couldn't find anything as good. I have to do a lot of research before i make this decision, but i am happy that i am opening my mind up to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you like ruby as programming language, but find rails to be just too much to take in it once, I'd recommend trying [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's also a ruby-based web framework, but it's a lot simpler than rails, and offers you a lot more control over how you want to set things up. For smaller projects, it's often a much better fit than Rails.

Comment: Rails just did too much because it was the first thing i started learning and i should have started with something more easier to get an understanding of general web development and now i that i do javascript/html and css i really feel like i understand and can be productive in web development. I really do like Ruby, i will take a look at sinatra, i hope it doesn't have activerecord, i prefer how i connect to mysql using netbeans. Can i just use ruby server side without a framework like rails or sinatra?

Comment: Sinatra is data-model-agnostic. It has almost nothing built in except for making the web interaction stuff easier. It pretty much *is* just ruby server-side. You can choose to `require 'active_record'` if you want to, but you don't have to. I often `require 'sequel'` for my database needs in Sinatra, but you can use any ruby gem you desire for database interaction.

Answer (score 2):

[`Python`](http://www.python.org/) language and [`Django`](http://www.djangoproject.com/) web framework are another good alternative. Both elegant and easy to get started with.

Comment: I noticed python is very much like Ruby, i also noticed that it is not tied so tightly with django like ruby is with rails. If i choose python would it be an easy transition if i know Ruby?

Comment: @RubyGladiator: Both Ruby and Python use dynamic, duck typing so you should be able to pick up on Python quickly coming from Ruby.